# Using a Drop Down and available Dates in a Content Type

Tags: nodes, datetime

I am running an event that spans a week.  During the event different vendors are able to have shows that run a few hours each.  What I would like to do is create a form for the vendors to fill out with their name, a description of the event and when it is happening.  I was originally using the date field, but it allows them to choose any date which has become a problem.

What I would like to do is have the actual days show up as a drop down with "Thursday, Friday, Saturday and the values of "3/1/2013", another one for Hour and a last one for minutes.

I figured out how to handle the views to display the information I want.  But what I can't figure out is a way to load this information onto a calendar.  I assume I have to combine all that information into a single database date field, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.  I am using Drupal 7 and, while getting better am still relatively new at Drupal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module. Read more here: http://drupal.org/node/262062

If you are already using that, then you probably need to change, `widget type` of the field to `Popup-Calender` or `Select List`

Comment: The date module is not capable of doing what is requested, at least not from what I've found.  Am I missing a feature of the date module?